# SimpleXML $xml->{$a} doesn't work

Tags: php

My code

```
<?php
        $a = 'node'
        $xml = simplexml_load_file('config.xml');
        echo $xml->node //work fine
        echo $xml->{$a};  //also work fine
        ?>

<?php
        $a = 'node[0]'
        $xml = simplexml_load_file('config.xml');
        echo $xml->node[0] //work fine
        echo $xml->{$a};  //DOESNT WORK!
        ?>
```

Why node[0] in a variable not work ? how can I solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`node` is the actual property name of the property that you want to access.  When you used `node[0]` instead of `node`, it looked for the property called `node[0]` instead of accessing the 0th index of the array `$xml->node`.  Basically, It looked for `node[0]` as if you typed `$xml->{"node[0]"}` instead of `node` (which is what you're expecting to do), and it can't find it.  So you'd want to try something like this instead:

```
echo $xml->{$a}[0];
```

Comment: $a = 'node';
$b = '0';
$num = (int)$b; echo $xml->{$a}[$num];  //Work fine  Thanks